# Ampersand view & lodash.debounce

Tags: javascript, lodash, ampersand.js

I am using lodash.debounce and ampersand-view.

I register my event handlers for the view's events, e.g.

```
events: {
        'click [data-hook~=power-on]': "power",
        'click [data-hook~=shutdown]': 'shutdown',
```

But I want to use debounce so that it doesn't trigger too frequently if the user spams the button.

However, the event registration appears to only take method name strings.

I'm sure I've missed something simple; but it's been a very long week..

**Solution**

I was using a method defined on the view (powerOn: function()), but that didn't work because it seems the this.powerOn reference wasn't found; I had to move the powerOn function outside of the view, then the following worked:

```
'click [data-hook~=power-on]': debounce(powerOn, 2000, { 'leading': true,  'trailing': false }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The callback may either be the name of a method on the view, or an actual function.
>   https://ampersandjs.com/docs/#ampersand-view-events

So you may use functions in events:

```
events: {
  'click [data-hook~=power-on]': _.debounce(callback)
}
```

Comment: I was using a method defined on the view (powerOn: function()), but that didn't work because it seems the this.powerOn reference wasn't found; I had to move the powerOn function outside of the view.